# Pandas - Count different values by date - A more efficient way?

Tags: python, pandas

Newbie here...

I have a data frame called 'yes_no', structured like this (but it has about 50K entries):

```
      Date        Yes/No
0     2020-10-27     No
1     2020-10-27     No
2     2020-10-26    Yes
3     2020-10-26    Yes
4     2020-10-26    No
5     2020-10-25    No
6     2020-10-25    Yes
7     2020-10-25    No
8     2020-10-24    Yes
9     2020-10-24    Yes
```

I need to count the number of yes and the number of nos for each date, and calculate the ratio, to end up with something like this:

```
     Date        Yes   No  Percentage
0   2020-10-27  1142  120    0.904913
1   2020-10-26  4112  388    0.913778
2   2020-10-25  1055   68    0.939448
3   2020-10-24  1012   86    0.921676
4   2020-10-23  1476  163    0.900549
5   2020-10-22  1633  182    0.899725
6   2020-10-21  1773  237    0.882090
7   2020-10-20  2332  246    0.904577
8   2020-10-19  2868  326    0.897934
9   2020-10-18   892  107    0.892893
10  2020-10-17   992  110    0.900181
11  2020-10-16  2106  207    0.910506
12  2020-10-15  5628  632    0.899042
13  2020-10-14  9304  937    0.908505
14  2020-10-13  8129  881    0.902220
```

I made it work with the following code, by going through a dictionary, but it's incredibly long:

```
by_date = {}
for date in yes_no['Date']:
  by_date[date] = yes_no.loc[yes_no['Date'] == date]


for date in by_date:
  by_date[date] =  by_date[date]['Yes/No'].value_counts()

for date in by_date:
  if 'No' not in by_date[date]:
    by_date[date]['No'] = 0

for date in by_date:
  if 'Yes' not in by_date[date]:
    by_date[date]['Yes'] = 0

for date in by_date:
  by_date[date] = [by_date[date]['Yes'], by_date[date]['No'], (by_date[date]['Yes']/(by_date[date]['Yes'] + by_date[date]['No']))]


df_yes = pd.DataFrame(list(by_date.values()),columns = ['Yes', 'No', 'Percentage'])
df_yes['Date'] = list(by_date.keys())
df_yes = df_yes[['Date', 'Yes', 'No', 'Percentage']]
```

It worked fine with a smaller data frame (1-2K), but this piece of code takes forever to go through with 50K entries:

```
for date in yes_no['Date']:
  by_date[date] = yes_no.loc[yes_no['Date'] == date]
```

There must be a better way to do this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this much more efficiently using vectorized operations (no explicit python looping). This means that all of our operations are being performed by the underlying C/C++ functions for huge speedups.

```
out = (df.groupby("Date")["Yes/No"]
       .value_counts()
       .unstack(fill_value=0)
       .rename_axis(columns=None)
       .eval("percentage = Yes / (Yes + No)")
      )

print(out)
            No  Yes  percentage
Date                           
2020-10-24   0    2    1.000000
2020-10-25   2    1    0.333333
2020-10-26   1    2    0.666667
2020-10-27   2    0    0.000000
```

Steps:

- `df.groupby("Date")["Yes/No"]`: group our dataframe by "Date" and select the "Yes/No" column from these groupings
- `.value_counts()`: Obtain the count of each "yes" and "no" within this column for each of these groupings.
- `.unstack(fill_value=0)`: Now that we have our counts, we make "Yes" and "No" into their own columns.
- `.rename_axis(columns=None)`: We have a funny looking column index name, I personally don't like these so I'm getting rid of it.
- `.eval("percentage = Yes / (Yes + No)")`: Create a new column called percentage, and assign it the values of all the "Yes" counts divided by the total response count ("Yes" + "No"

Comment: Thanks - this solved it neatly and it's almost instantaneous.

Answer (score 1):

```
# groupby date and yes/no columns and get the size
# then pivot 
new_df = df.groupby(['Date', 'Yes/No'], as_index=False).size().pivot('Date', 'Yes/No', 'size').replace(np.nan, 0)
# divide the yes column by the size of each group
new_df['percent_yes'] = new_df['Yes'] / new_df.sum(1)
print(new_df)

Yes/No       No  Yes  percent_yes
Date                             
2020-10-24  0.0  2.0     1.000000
2020-10-25  2.0  1.0     0.333333
2020-10-26  1.0  2.0     0.666667
2020-10-27  2.0  0.0     0.000000
```

Comment: use `unstack(fill_value=0)` in place of pivot

Comment: You'll need to remove `as_index=False` from the groupby call to use the `unstack(...)` method

Answer (score 0):

You should look into one-hot encoding. pandas uses [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)

My solution would be:

```py
df_new = pd.get_dummies(yes_no, columns=["Yes/No"]).groupby("Date").sum().rename(columns={"Yes/No_No":"No", "Yes/No_Yes":"Yes"}
```

And then you can calculate the percentage easily.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple way to do this, maybe some more elegant ways are available:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Yes_no': ['yes','no','yes', 'yes', 'no','yes','no','yes', 'yes', 'no','yes','no','yes', 'yes', 'no','yes','no','yes', 'yes', 'no'],
    'Dates': ['2019-07-01','2019-07-01','2019-07-01', '2019-07-03', '2019-07-03','2019-07-03','2019-07-07','2019-07-07', '2019-07-07', '2019-07-07','2019-07-07','2019-07-07','2019-07-07', '2019-07-07', '2019-07-07','2019-07-07','2019-07-07','2019-07-07', '2019-07-07', '2019-07-07']})
dff = df.groupby(['Yes_no','Dates'])['Yes_no'].count()
dff.unstack().T
```

to create your extra column with proportions, simply define a new column

```
dff['prop']=dff['no']/dff['yes']
```